# Prime number tester that can effectively utilize an arbitrary number of parallel threads

Tags: linux, multi-threading

I am looking for a Linux program that can test for primality of a lengthy integer, (at least *10^8* digits long), and is built to increase performance arbitrarily as the degree of parallelism is increased arbitrarily. There is no limit on the amount of RAM required by the software.